# Ordenamiento de array en Javascript con .sort no funciona como se esperaba

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones, objeto, else

El problema es que se creó una variable y se ordenó el array de una forma, y verificando con un console.log aparece todo bien, pero cuando se crea una segunda variable y se ordena el array de una segunda forma y se verifica con otro console.log, no solo cambia el orden de esa variable sino también el orden de la anterior.
Creo entender que esto se debe a la diferencia entre almacenamiento de valor y almacenamiento de referencia pero no entiendo bien la solución. Por el momento, al ir comentando el código es que se soluciona...

```js
const jugadores = [

  {
    apellido: 'Riquelme',
    nombre: 'Juan Román',
    titulosGanados: 11,
  },

  {
    apellido: 'Palermo',
    nombre: 'Martín',
    titulosGanados: 14,
  },

  {
    apellido: 'Schiavi',
    nombre: 'Rolando',
    titulosGanados: 9,
  },

  { 
    apellido: 'Battaglia',
    nombre: 'Sebastián',
    titulosGanados: 17,
  }
]

// por orden alfabético según apellido

const apellido = jugadores.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.apellido < b.apellido) {return -1}
  else {return 1};
})
console.log(apellido)

// Orden según títulos ganados (de mayor a menor)

 const titulos = jugadores.sort((a, b) => b.titulosGanados - a.titulosGanados)
 console.log(titulos)

// Orden alfabético descendente según nombre 

 const nombre = jugadores.sort((a, b) => {
   if (a.nombre > b.nombre) {return -1}
   else {return 1};
 })
 console.log(nombre);
```

Comment: El fragmento de código parece funcionar bien. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código de la segunda variable y cómo la ordenas.

Comment: allí coloqué el código que faltaba @Triby

Answer (score 1):

El *"problema"* es que esas otras variables son una referencia de la original y, al modificar una, se modifican también las demás.

Ejemplo:

```js
let numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
// Ordenar ascendente
let asc = numbers.sort();
console.log(asc);
// Ordenar descendente
let desc = numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b - a;
});
console.log(desc);
// Al final, las tres variables hacen referencia al mismo arreglo
// Y por eso el resultado es igual para todas
console.log(numbers, asc, desc);
```

En tu caso, conviene convertir a cadena con [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) y volver a interpretar como objeto con [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) para eliminar las referencias y que realmente se cree un nuevo objeto:

```js
const jugadores = [
  {
    apellido: 'Riquelme',
    nombre: 'Juan Román',
    titulosGanados: 11,
  },
  {
    apellido: 'Palermo',
    nombre: 'Martín',
    titulosGanados: 14,
  },
  {
    apellido: 'Schiavi',
    nombre: 'Rolando',
    titulosGanados: 9,
  },
  { 
    apellido: 'Battaglia',
    nombre: 'Sebastián',
    titulosGanados: 17,
  }
];

// Para usarlo varias veces, es mejor crear una función
function newObject(obj) {
    // Convertir a cadena
    let newObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
    // Devolver como objeto
    return JSON.parse(newObj);
    // Podría ser una sola línea:
    // return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

// por orden alfabético según nombre
const nombre = newObject(jugadores).sort((a, b) => {
    // Se usa localeCompare para que funcione correctamente con acentos
    return a.nombre.localeCompare(b.nombre);
});
// Cada objeto es diferente
console.log(jugadores, nombre);
```